# MVC5 Google+ Authentication - Force Google Signin after logout

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, google-plus

I have just wired up MVC5 with google+ authentication exactly as per this excelent guide:

http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google-plus/

My question is this. Once my Google Account has been authenticated and I am logged in to my application, I cant seem to force the user to be able to logout totally.

Clicking logout drops me back to my external login screen with the Google+ button, but clicking the button takes me straight in to my application again.

Is it possible to clear the authenticated user completely once logout is pressed?

I tried adding this prior to the login procedure, but to no avail:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to clear the authenticated user completely once logout is pressed?

No, that's not possible. The user is still authenticated in his Google account, having all his cookies present. You have absolutely no control over that. It is the responsibility of the user to decide whether he wants to sign out from his Google account, not yours. Since your application integrates a Google OAuth authentication you will have to live with that. The `AuthenticationManager.SignOut();` simply clears the cookies out from your application domain.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I kinda understand the reason by this but I find it difficult to understands why no 'hard' logout option exists, or the ability to hold the Google sign in to the session only. For use on a shared machine, I reckon that this method of authentication is pretty flawed.